# How do I find onhover event using firebug which is written in CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I'm using firebug to inspect elements, but i couldn't find how onhover event is running on my website on menu items so that it'll show sub menu of it. i need to find that event so that i'll remove it, i don't need it anymore. 
it's not coming through js, it's coming from CSS can anybody help me

```
<ul id="dropline">
    <li><a href="messages.php">Messages</a>|
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <div>
            <ul class="blank">
           <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

i think this is the id. which create it's sub menu, but i don't find hove event in css. 
this is my css

```
 #menu ul {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }
 #dropline {
    background: url("../ulback.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Firebug style]

Are you trying to accomplish this? You can see :hover which will show you styles being applied in hover state only.